# #php compare two times with strtotime parse function doesn't work

Tags: php, time, compare, strtotime

I am struggling with comparing two times.

```
$t1 = "55:10.01";
$t2 = "11.2";

$res = strtotime($t1) > strtotime($t2);
print($t1.' > '.$t2.' = '.($res?'TRUE':'FALSE'));
```

And the result is FALSE. If I understand correctly, PHP documentation says that both strings $t1 and $t2 should be parsed by strtotime, but... :)

Any idea what am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: `11.2.` is *not* a valid date format. Thus `strotime()` returns false. And, 11.2 of *what*? Cheese? You gotta help PHP out and give it  a better idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Well, actually strtotime($t1) returns false, while $t2 seems to be fine (11.2 seconds). Referencing to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php I assume both times are correct. The other answer is I don't understand it at all...

Comment: Buddhi Abeyratne - my mistake, there ought to be $t1 and $t2 instead. I have just corrected that.

Comment: strtotime is really terrible. I believe even the php himself does not know which format is suitable for that! Search for createFromFormat method of DateTime. Sorry but I'm so tired to do that now!

Comment: @Ahmad why do you say that 
its a useful function only its misused in this case 
it easily makes life easy by encoding things to unix time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$t1 = "55:10.01";
$t2 = "11.2";
if (date($t1) > date($t2)){
  $res = 'true';
}else{
  $res = 'false';
}
print($t1.' > '.$t2.' = '.$res);
```

Comment: so what is the difference?

Comment: wait i know why this is wrong 
this is unix time and the grater than doesn't know its time it thinks its an integer 
wait i'll fix my code

Comment: that is correct, it works fine! :) But it is confusing - date function works better than specialized time function... Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: your code works fine btw i didnt spot this at first upon further testing i saw you were trying to `strtotime` 55 hours 
you cant do that its 24hours. so your code works fine 
your test scenario was wrong.
and we call made fools of our self